# Compound formula without decimals

Tags: percentages

I am trying to write a compound formula in a programming language that doesn't have decimal places.

For something that I thought was going to be simple.. I seem to be struggling a bit..

Using Excel as a test area I have written;

```
1 * (1 + 0.0025) ^ 2212
```

Which equals 250.4 (rounded).

I'm struggling to write this without the 0.0025 (representing 0.25%). Is there a way I can multiply this equation out so that I don't have to use 0.0025 to represent 0.25%?

For example, have 0.25% represented as 25?

Thanks!

Comment: 0.25% = 25/10000.

Comment: Does your programming language have floating point numbers?

Comment: I agree with quasi, you can write
$$
(1 + 0.0025)^{2212} = (1 + 25/1000)^{2212}
$$
However, it seems odd that you would do mathematical calculations in a programming language that does not have decimal places. Especially with percentages, the decimal places can make a huge difference.

Comment: Nope, does not have floating point. The language is called Solidity (used for Ethereum). I have tried (1+25/1000) and it does not seem to work as intended...

Comment: @MitchellNZ: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity